# Querying SQL server that contains ranges of data

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a connection to a SQL server via Excel 2007. The data looks like:

```
A0001-A9999,X9999-X9999 | 1234
B0001-B9999             | 5678
C0001-C4999             | 1111
C4500-C4999             | 1112
C5000-C9999,D0001-D9999 | 2222
...
```

The first column is a range of values where the second column is the value that should be outputted. Examples: an input of "C4000" would return "1111", and an input of "C4600" would return "1111,1112".

How would I write code that would allow the user of a form to enter any one input in a cell on a worksheet and get the output in another cell? The idea would be to hit a button that would activate a macro that would truncate the data and report the results. I am proficient in writing VBA code and would prefer to use that, otherwise I am not adverse to trying to learn SQL.

The user in this case  knows to always put a letter followed by four numbers as the input. I do not have the ability to edit the data in the table, just to pull from the SQL server.

Comment: I would love to break up the information into a much simpler form, but unfortunately I do not have the power to change the tables, I can only pull from it. Because there are about 26,000 lines of data pulled from the SQL, I am afraid that the computer power to break each of those rows into 1NF in a separate sub would render calculation times to be crazy.

Comment: Note your 3rd and 4th ranges overlap :(

Comment: What does "pull the data from the server mean?" Is this an embedded query? Or is the VBA being used with ADO to get the data? In an case you will have to parse the data into usable form - I'd split the first column into "letterCode", "lo", and "hi" and add rows for those with multiple ranges.

Comment: Yes, there are in fact many different overlapping ranges, and I just gave a simplified version of the data. Pardon my use of non-technical jargon. From Data->From Other Sources->From Microsoft Query, I connected to the SQL server, selected the columns from the table I want, and use the pre-filter to select only rows that pertain to me (I think the SQL translation is: WHERE column = something). I haven't used VBA with ADO yet, but it's something I'm reading up on now.

Answer (score 2):

The question is vague as to which tools you want to use. But the solution will not be a SQL solution. You can always set up PowerPivot in Excel to accomplish this.